How much of the surviving ancient Egyptian text has been found?
It is like oil. Even if we can not say how much oil has not been found yet, we still can have various estimates.
As far I know, the currently available total mass of ancient Egyptian text is about 5 million words (wiki).
What do experts of the topic might say, have we found nearly all, or there is some room for some new finds?
About 5 million words of ancient Egyptian text. That remained from a civilization. Question is, how much might be found in the future? Practically nothing? Or half Egypt is filled with buried stones, we only did not have the money to dig them out?

Are you asking how much Ancient Egyptian Writing there ever was anywhere ever? Like if someone wrote a note in the sand with a stick. that counts?

Yes, I think it would count (although probably such sand graphs would not last too long). About 5million words. That remained from them. Question is, how much might be found in the future? Practically nothing? Or half Egypt is filled with buryed stones, we only did not have the money to dig them out?

I don't see any expert willing to hazard a guess.
As an archeologist says on a relevant Reddit thread:

only a small minority of burials, even elite burials, have been discovered. I wouldn't hold my breath for another Howard Carter moment, though--Egyptian tombs have been picked over for literally thousands of years.

In 2023, for the first time in a century a major new Book of the Dead was found. Over recent decades new shards of inscribed pottery have been found by the thousands, but many simply have the same character or word written repeatedly. So incrementally the known corpus does continue to increase but it's probably impossible to give a meaningful number of what's left.

While I very value your expert answer, I strongly disagree calling such estimations hazardous guess. That you can not produce a google map list of the not yet discovered Egyptian things, does not mean that you could not have an educated guess, how much might exist and where they are. That makes an expert. For example, viewing a software developer CV and a city, I can have an educated guess, how much can he earn in that city. Even if I had not ever seen the guy neither the city.

Hazard, verb 1. venture to say (something). "he hazarded a guess"

Ok thx! :-) I still suggest to use "educated guess" instead hazardous guess, but okay.

They  didn't say "hazardous guess" though, and that isn't what the phrase implies

This answer is IMHO the proper approach to take with this question. Consider it "The Popcorn Principle": If you're still hearing a substantial amount of popping, then the popcorn probably isn't done yet.
